# Javascript object method not working when called

Tags: javascript

This is my situation

```js
//The object
var obj = {
    celToFah: function() {
      var celsiusInn = document.getElementById('celsius-input').value;
      var fahrenheit;
      fahrenheit = (celsiusInn * 9 / 5) + 32; document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = fahrenheit;
    },
    fahToCel: function() {
      var fahrenheitInn = document.getElementById('fahrenheit-input').value;
      var celsius;
      celsius = (fahrenheitInn - 32) * (5 / 9); document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = celsius;
    }
  }
  //The action
  <
  button onclick = "obj.fahToCel()"
class = "btn btn-primary" > Calc < /button>
```

the main error is with the object oriented method im trying to use. When write it on the script it works , but when try to use ab object it doesn't
please help!!

Comment: "*It just doesnt work please help!!*", what doesn't work? Please include any errors and expected behaviour!

Comment: Your “one-liner” function there is missing semicolons in several places.

Comment: you probably have a few errors in the browser *developer* tools console that will help you make it work

Comment: @0stone0 when I click the button in html it doesnt work, how can i show that to you

Answer (score 0):

you're missing 2 semicolons in both functions.

You should always try to isolate problems more and more until you find the problem.

In your case you should have spread your one-liner object and isolate both functions and try to define each in your browser's *devtools* (F12) and see if it runs without a problem. it is helpful when you're having a hard time debugging manually with your eyes ;)

```js
var obj = { 
    celToFah: function() { 
      var celsiusInn = document.getElementById('celsius-input').value; 
      var fahrenheit; 
      fahrenheit = (celsiusInn * 9/5) + 32  // <---- missing semicolon
      document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = fahrenheit; 
    }, 
    
    fahToCel: function() { 
      var fahrenheitInn = document.getElementById('fahrenheit-input').value; 
      var celsius; 
      celsius = (fahrenheitInn - 32) * (5/9)   // <---- missing semicolon
      document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = celsius; 
    } 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="obj.fahToCel()" class="btn btn-primary"> Calc</button>
<input id="fahrenheit-input" value="100" />
<output id="result1"></output>
```

Comment: Ok thanks , but the main error is with the object oriented method im trying to use. When write it on the script it works , but when try to use ab object it doesnt

Comment: it works, try to run my code and click the button. you **must add *semicolons*** where I placed the comments, because you write everything in a *single-line* of code.